# The return type of java.lang.Object getTimeout() is incompatible with org.gradle.api.provider.Property in org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am facing an issue while building my application using Gradle, kindly have a look into the below error message.

> Groovy:The return type of java.lang.Object getTimeout() in com.test.gradle.MemtoolProgram is incompatible with org.gradle.api.provider.Property in org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask**

Sample Code:

```
public class CustomtoolProgram extends DefaultTask {

def timeout=300;

}
```

can anyone of you help to resolve this issue?

Comment: easiest way to solve it is to rename `timeout` property into something else, like `timeoutSecons`

Answer (score 0):

There is already a getter method called `getTimeout()` that comes from extending `DefaultTask`, and it is of a different type (a `Provider<Duration>`) than what you are using (an integer I assume). This is why Groovy reports an error. The solution depends on what you are trying to do.

`def timeout` in Groovy declares a new variable and as it is public it will provide you with getters and setters. As the type differs from the inherited one, you are basically trying to override the same getter method but with a different return type. This is not allowed. In either case, you are not supposed to shadow or override these things. So you will have to find another name for your own variable if this is what you like to do. In this case, you probably also want to use the Provider API instead as this is more flexible.

Example:

```
class CustomtoolProgram extends DefaultTask {
    @Internal
    final Property<Integer> myTimeout = project.objects.property(Integer).convention(300)
}
```

In the above code fragment, `@Internal` means that the property is not to be taken into account for up-to-date checking. It is also `final` as properties should not be reassigned.

If you instead like to set the provided task timeout, you will have to do it in a different way. First of all, the `timeout` property is a Provider, so you can't assign values to it directly outside the Groovy DSL. Secondly, it takes a Duration and not an integer, and lastly it should be set in a constructor and not as a new variable.

Example:

```
class CustomtoolProgram extends DefaultTask {
    CustomtoolProgram() {
        timeout.set(Duration.ofMillis(300))
    }
}
```

However, if you like to define a task that runs an external program, you should consider using the [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Exec.html) task.

Hope this was helpful.